# Duplicate records found in What's New in Workplace in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am passing from one of the strange issue in What's New Section in workplace at Dynamic CRM 2011.I am not sure but I found duplicate record in Whats new section some time.For Example if I close some Task then I found two entries in What's New section like

```
Admin User closed test for Test as Completed

Admin User closed test for Test as Completed
```

I am not sure why this happen can anyone please help me.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem, I am experiencing the same thing and google a lot with no results. Please share if you found it.

Comment: I have checked and found that the Issue is with roll up which you have installed.when you installed the rollup the Activity Feed PlugIn has been registered. Activity Feed PlugIn is responsible for displaying the data in What's New section and I found that there duplicates steps is there in PlugIn Registration Tool.for ex.create of phonecall. so there are two same steps found in activity feed PlugIn. so,the data is displayed twice.so,I have disabled one and then  check it was not going to duplicating now.

Comment: Thank Kartik Patel, I follow your instruction and the issue is gone :)

Comment: I am very happy as it help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked and found that the Issue is with roll up which you have installed.when you installed the rollup the Activity Feed PlugIn has been registered. Activity Feed PlugIn is responsible for displaying the data in What's New section and I found that there duplicates steps is there in PlugIn Registration Tool.for ex.create of phonecall. so there are two same steps found in activity feed PlugIn. so,the data is displayed twice.so,I have disabled one and then check it was not going to duplicating now.